# Filter Observable<Any>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I work with Typescript and angular 4.
I have 2 list (rxjs/Rx)

```
...
 myList: Observable<MyClass[]>;
 filteredList: Observable<MyClass[]>;
...
```

I want filtered myList and push result in the filteredList
by looking at the property string of MyClass is equal to '123' or another string
The filteredlist is mapped on a autcomplete angular
and I have this code

```
 this.filteredList= this.myForm.get("myautocomplete").valueChanges .startWith(null) .map(???);
```

What's the best way to resolve this problem?

I can not do it !

Thanks for your help

Comment: first, those are not lists, they are observables that on an event will give you an array of MyClass

Comment: I recovers that, then i have populate a autocomplete material angular with a filter string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
myList: Observable<MyClass[]>;
filteredList = myList.map(items => 
  items.filter(item => item.string === '123'));
```

Autocomplete example:

```
filteredList = myForm.get("autocomplete").valueChanges 
  .startWith('')
  .combineLatest(myList)
  .map(([q, items]) => items.filter(item => item.string === q));
```

Comment: `(items || []).filter(item => item.string === (q || ''))`, quick & dirty :P But you should make sure they are not null...

Comment: Amazing you're a genious ... I found a another solution in my total code with toPromise ... Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, since typescript is based on JS, so if you want to know if there's a method to do this or that, go check it out.

You want to use `.filter` on an array :

-From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

`The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.`

So if you want to filter the number 0 on the array [0,1,2,3] named `ar` for instance :

```
filteredAr = ar.filter(entry => entry !== 0);
```

But since its an observable, you have to subscribe to its changes and change `filteredList` type...

Comment: I use this but it doesn't work
myList.map(xx=> xx.filter(item=> item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0) it returns a Observable

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work ? Its returning nothing ? You have any console output error ?

Comment: Maybe its just because you're not returning it ? You have to return something from your map, the .filter method in this case.

Comment: In fact i have a autocomplete on this.filteredList= this.myForm.get("myautocomplete").valueChanges .startWith(null) .map(???); how do youy do ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, this is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have two observables.
You want to take first one and transform it to a bit. You can use methid `.map` for it.

```
filteredList = myList.map(arr => arr.filter(x => x['stringPropOfMyClass'] === '123'));
```

I suggest you first get the [basics of Observables down](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754).

Comment: In fact i have a autocomplete on this.filteredList= this.myForm.get("myautocomplete").valueChanges
                .startWith(null)
                .map(???); how do youy do ?

Comment: Thanks it's very interesting ... and a little complicated :)